# Get focus on a JTextField inside a CardLayout

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield, cardlayout

I have a `JTextField` inside a `JPanel` A which is a part of `CardLayout`. When this A gets shown, I want to set the focus automatically to the `JTextField` (i.e. the cursor is flashing in the text field so the user doesn't need to click on it to enable the input). I tried calling `requestFocusInWindow()` on the `JTextField` object at initialization, but that doesn't seem to work. Do I need to call this method every time when A gets displayed? Thanks.

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://pscode.org/sscce.html).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe you can try `requestFocusInWindow()` when the panel is shown ?

something like this?

```
    jPanel.addComponentListener(new ComponentAdapter() {
        @Override 
        public void componentShown(java.awt.event.ComponentEvent e) 
        {
            jTextField.requestFocusInWindow();
        }
    });
```